# Xbox One - backward compatibility duplicates

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I have added new generic question regarding Xbox One backward compatibility:

[Can I play against or with Xbox 360 players through my Xbox One?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245132/can-i-play-against-or-with-xbox-360-players-through-my-xbox-one)

The question by itself should prove useful based on these examples (there may be more):

[Can I play Battlefield Hardline online between an Xbox 360 and Xbox One?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219122/can-i-play-battlefield-hardline-online-between-an-xbox-360-and-xbox-one)
[Can I play COD: Ghosts with my Xbox 360 friends if I have an Xbox One?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149168/can-i-play-cod-ghosts-with-my-xbox-360-friends-if-i-have-an-xbox-one)
[Can an Xbox 360 and an Xbox One play online together with Disney Infinity 2.0?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191998/can-an-xbox-360-and-an-xbox-one-play-online-together-with-disney-infinity-2-0)
[If my friend has GTA 5 for 360 and I have one can I invite them to my game online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201057/if-my-friend-has-gta-5-for-360-and-i-have-one-can-i-invite-them-to-my-game-onlin)
[Can my son play Minecraft with his XBOX 360 friends with his XBOX One?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232224/can-my-son-play-minecraft-with-his-xbox-360-friends-with-his-xbox-one)

I imagine that since this new feature has just been rolled out to everyone on the Xbox One, we could potentially get more questions along these lines.

Should we/I mark these questions as duplicates to the new generic question?

Note - this doesn't concern the recent meta regarding GTA V consolidation, as that was addressing an issue with cross-platform (i.e. PC and Playstation platforms too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most definetly. As Eric points out, there is a good chance that more questions will pop up, as new 360 games are "turned on". However, you have provided a link to the official list of supported titles, which I think is adequate in this particular case.

As such, I have suggested closing the questions you list as duplications. One already has been, due to other efforts regarding GTA V and cross play, and it looks like the others are on their way.

Comment: It would be worth considering if we should do the same with PC and Xbox cross play, once it becomes more available, and if we do, wether we should make note of the ability to stream the xbox one directly through a windows 10 computer.

Comment: I don't want to cover that in this meta/solution, but it may prove useful to give a similar approach if possible.  Minus a few hours on Minecraft beta I haven't had the chance to put much time into Windows 10 games, let alone cross play.

Comment: Probably a "see if questions pop up" sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these issues will always crop up and unless you would want to maintain a complete list of titles, their compatibility, and their respective cross-platform support. Hence, I believe your answer is lacking due to the fact that it depends on more than two factors.

Firstly it depends on whether you are playing an emulated 360 game or an Xbox One game. IF you are playing the latter, it merely depends on the developers/publishers wish to support cross-platform play. This has been done and will most likely be supported in the future. Note that there are many ways for cross-platform support. It can be on the same console family (World of Tanks; Xbox 360 and Xbox One cross-play) or across different platforms altogether (Elite: Dangerous; PC, Mac and Xbox One Cross-play).

If you are playing an emulated 360 version of your game then your answer provides the right amount of detail.

So all in all it is more difficult than to say that if you emulate, you can and otherwise you can't.

Comment: XNA was a bit before my time. And yeah, if I want to ask for proof, the burden lies more heavily with you. Answers can be downvoted, comments can not,and your hostility to comply suggests you simply cant.

Comment: Seeing as you removed your previous comments, I see no reason to further indulge in this discussion. If you wish to downvote my answer because you feel you have contrary evidence, please do so. Seeing that the games I stated are cross-platform and run on developer (not Microsoft) servers, I feel like I have provided ample proof to my claims.

Comment: Again, you have listed no proof to what you are saying. Everything you list references live servers for network. Microsoft make both windows and xbox, and have been behind the push to crossplay xbox and pc. All of this is redundant by both the context of the question being asked, and the fact that we dont a swer questions with speculation of the future. The only legitimate issue I see is the potential that the title may not be supported, but as OP has provided reference to the official list, I have put the duplication to a vote.

Comment: What I wrote is not a speculation. Elite: Dangerous is available for Mac as well. Again, the issue seems really straight forward and I don't see why it needs further proof beyond the obvious.

Comment: Irregardless, a moot point. Updating my answer

Comment: Firstly, I adjusted the answer to cover your concerns. At the moment it appears WoT is the only 360 vs. One game. If other examples can be found I will add them. You are right that potentially in the future this approach may not fit. If that is correct then I will do the best to change the answer/remove it or whatever actions are correct.

Comment: Secondly, I don't want to widen the scope beyond 360 vs. One. I never intended to go along that path. This is more to do with confusion over backwards compatibility on Xbox consoles.